# NameError: name 'images' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to import some images to my local computer  from amazon using their api for data analysis

This is my code I am getting this error.Don't know what to do Please suggest some solution

**Code**

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

for index, row in images.iterrows():
        url = row['large_image_url']
        response = requests.get(url)
        img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        img.save('images/15k_images/'+row['asin']+'.jpeg')
```

**Error**

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-36-ce8803db815e> in <module>()
>       9 from io import BytesIO
>      10 
> ---> 11 for index, row in images.iterrows():
>      12         url = row['large_image_url']
>      13         response = requests.get(url)
>
> NameError: name 'images' is not defined
> ```

Comment: What do you think `images.iterrows()` is?

Comment: From api i got url of images so may be that it is

Comment: Nope, that's not it.

Comment: I am a newbie to this its my first time  i m trying it so i also don't know major about this field.i am learning it btw it will be grateful if you can help me explaining what it is :)